# Call method from another ng-app in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have 2 ng-app block on same page. One for listing items, and the other one is for insert. I want to call listing function after I have finished insert. 
I have tried something but I couldn't succeeded in. 
I found some documents about calling functions on same ng-app but i need to call a function from another ng-app.

Here is my code, please help.

```
<body>
<div id="UserControllerDiv" ng-app="UserTableApp" ng-controller="UsersController" class="form-group">
    <br /><br />
    <p>Search : <input type="text" ng-model="search" /></p>
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Middle Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="u in users | filter:search">
                <td>{{ u.FirstName }} </td>
                <td>{{ u.MiddleName }} </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<br />
<div id="UserFormDiv" ng-app="UserFormApp" ng-controller="UserFormCtr" class="form-group">
    <table class="form-group">
        <tr>
            <td>First Name</td>
            <td> : </td>
            <td><input type="text" ng-model="FirstName" class="" /> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Middle Name</td>
            <td> : </td>
            <td><input type="text" ng-model="MiddleName" /> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <button ng-click="submit()">Save</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<script>
    var userTableApp = angular.module("UserTableApp", []);
    userTableApp.controller("UsersController",
        function UsersController($scope, $http) {
            $http.get("http://localhost:10160/UserService/Users")
            .success(function (response) { $scope.users = response; });
        });
    var userFormApp = angular.module("UserFormApp", []);
    userFormApp.controller("UserFormCtr",
        function UserFormCtr($scope, $http) {
            $scope.submit = function () {
                var dataObj = {
                    FirstName: $scope.FirstName,
                    MiddleName: $scope.MiddleName
                };
                var res = $http.post("http://localhost:10160/UserService/AddUser", dataObj);
                res.success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

                    /****** Here I want to call the UsersController function of UserTableApp  ************/
                    /* I tried the code below but it did not work */
                    var scope = angular.element(document.getElementById("UserControllerDiv")).scope();
                    scope.$apply(function () { scope.UsersController($scope, $http); });
                    /*************************************************************************************/

                });
                res.error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    alert("failure message: " + JSON.stringify({ data: data }));
                });
            }
        });
    angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("UserFormDiv"), ['UserFormApp']);
</script>
```

Thank you for all your help...

Comment: Do you really need to have two separate apps?

Comment: Actually it is not for this method. But this is a sample for my usage.

Comment: one ng-app should be enough for a single page application :)

Comment: I know i will do so If i cannot fond anu solution.

Comment: @enginbilici then why you don't do it first, I agree you are separating modules, but do gather them inside single module before bootstraping it on  html like `angular.module('app',['app1','app2','app3'])`

Comment: Yes you are all right. I will try it first. But at that time, if someone finds an answer, please share :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you call function from other controller app.

```
 var scope = angular.element(document.getElementById("UserControllerDiv")).scope();
                scope.yourfunctionName();
```

And the flow will go to the Function mentioned.
For assurance you can check presence of your method in scope object in console.
You were just about right.

Comment: Tried this. Unfortunately, "scope is undefined".